# asymptotic behavior of ${n \choose \lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}$

Tags: probability

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $0<\alpha<1$.
What is the asymptotic behavior of ${n \choose \lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}$?

Using Stirling's approximation one can find that:

$${n \choose \lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}\sim 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n \alpha (1- \alpha)}} \frac{n^n}{{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}{(n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor)}^{n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}}$$

Now I wonder if this hideous expression can be further simplified.

Comment: Got something from an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\frac1n\log\frac{n^n}{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}(n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor)^{n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}}=-\frac{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}n\cdot\log\frac{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}n-\frac{n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}n\cdot\log\frac{n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}n$$
and that $$\alpha\leqslant\frac{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}n\lt\alpha+\frac1n,$$ hence $$\frac{n^n}{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}(n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor)^{n-\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}}=\mathrm e^{\beta n+O(1)},$$ with $$\beta=-\alpha\log\alpha-(1-\alpha)\log(1-\alpha)$$ and the most precise asymptotics this can yield seems to be $${n \choose \lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}=\frac{\mathrm e^{\beta n}}{\sqrt{n}}\,\mathrm e^{O(1)}.$$

Comment: I know this is an old answer. But I believe there is a mistake here. Namely, $\lfloor{\alpha n \rfloor} \log \lfloor{\alpha n \rfloor}$ is not $\alpha \log \alpha + O(1)$, but rather $ \alpha \log \alpha n + O(\log n)$ as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

$\log{n\choose k}\approx nH(k/n)$, where H is the binary entropy function. See 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient