# asymptotics for binomials

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, entropy

What is a published reference for the asymptotic equivalent of $ n \choose k$ with $k$ linear in $n$? I want both the entropy function and the denominator in $\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: [tag:reference-request]?

Comment: I suspect that the asymptotics of ${n \choose \alpha n}$ are in "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer, but I don't have a copy at hand right now.

Comment: Also, this is possibly a repeat of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004005/asymptotic-behavior-of-n-choose-lfloor-alpha-n-rfloor or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109921/limit-of-frac1n-logn-choose-np-without-using-stirlings-formula?rq=1

Comment: The asymptotics in "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer p.232 are incorrect. The term in $\sqrt{n}$ is missing.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients/236511#236511

Answer (score 3):

The following appears (with proof) in Ash, *Information Theory*, 1965 as Lemma 4.7.1:

$$
\frac{2^{nH(p,1-p)}}{\sqrt{8np(1-p)}} \le {n \choose np} \le \frac{2^{nH(p,1-p)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi np(1-p)}} \,,
$$
Here $H(p,1-p):=-p \log_2 p - (1-p) \log_2 (1-p)$ is the binary entropy function.

Answer (score 1):

These [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7872) by [David Galvin](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/) state the asymptotic expression (see the beginning of Section 3.1):
\begin{align*}
   \binom{n}{\alpha n} &=
      \frac{2^{H(\alpha)n}}{\sqrt{2\pi\, n\, \alpha(1-\alpha)}}
      [1+o(1)]
      \qquad\text{as $n\to\infty$}
\end{align*}
for $0<\alpha<1$.  He does not provide a proof, only that it follows from Stirling's approximation, so I assume the proof must be straightforward.

Comment: This solves my question completely. But what about a sum of binomial coefficients like the volume of a hamming ball of radius $\alpha n$